# Updating my 3GS from iOS 4.1 to 6.1.6

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way i can upgrade my iPhone 3GS from iOS 4.1 to 6.1.6 without using a computer?

Comment: You should try to get a new iPhone, like an iPhone 4, for pretty cheap on eBay. iOS 4 makes this 3GS more desirable to collectors than all the ones running 6.1.6

Comment: I don't know if iOS 4 supported OTA updates. Even if you can do that I don't know if it's a good idea, it might run slow and still won't work with new apps. How about getting a 5S, those are pretty inexpensive now.

Comment: Your best option is getting a 5s and making it last until iOS 12-13 comes out, and then you can get the iPhone 9s

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

OTA [Over the Air] updates are only available on devices that shipped with iOS 5 or later.
Your only alternative is a computer running iTunes.

Source: [Wikipedia - iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS)